# How to prevent maven assembly plugin from renaming artifacts

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin, rpm-maven-plugin

In my maven project I have to a (fairly large amount) of RPMs. For convenience during deployment I want to assemble all the RPMs into a single archive (.tar.gz). The assembly runs in a separate module which depends on all the RPM modules.

For this I have the following `assembly.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<assembly>
    <id>myproject-rpm-package</id>
    <formats>
        <format>tar.gz</format>
    </formats>
    <baseDirectory>${project.parent.parent.name}-${project.version}-rpms</baseDirectory>

    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
            <includes>
                <!-- Include only the RPMs -->
                <include>*:rpm</include>
            </includes>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

This works well, but it renames all my RPMS to follow the format: `<projectname>-<version>.rpm`. Losing useful properties in the RPM naming convention: `<rpm name>-<version>-<release>.noarch.rpm`. The RPMS still work fine.

My suspicion is that this comes from the maven assembly property [outputFileNameMapping](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_dependencySet).

Is my assumption correct? If so, how can I prevent the renaming of my RPM files by the assembly plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is correct. The `maven-assembly-plugin` will rename all the dependencies of your assembly project into the format specified by [`outputFileNameMapping`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_dependencySet):

> Sets the mapping pattern for all dependencies included in this assembly.
>   Default value is: `${artifact.artifactId}-${artifact.version}${dashClassifier?}.${artifact.extension}`.

The documentation contains [all values](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/faq.html#outputFileNameMapping) that you can specify in this attribute:

> #### Which properties can be used in the outputFileNameMapping parameter.
>
> You can use :
>
> - all system or maven properties available in your build with the syntax `${myProperty}`.
> - all environment variables with `${env.XXX}` where `XXX` is the environment variable.
> - the special `${dashClassifier?}` property (see above).
> - all artifacts attributes ( from the [`Artifact`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-artifact/apidocs/org/apache/maven/artifact/Artifact.html) class) like :
>
>   - `${artifact.groupId}` : The artifact groupId.
>   - `${artifact.artifactId}` : The artifact artifactId.
>   - `${artifact.version}` : The artifact classifier.
>   - `${artifact.baseVersion}` : The artifact base version (For a SNAPSHOT it will be always -SNAPSHOT and not its timestamp even if you didn't built it yourself).
>   - `${artifact.classifier}` : The artifact classifier.
>   - `${artifact.scope}` : The artifact scope.
>   - ...
>
> You can use `${module.XXXXX}` when using it for your project modules artifacts.

It looks like it is missing from the documentation, but starting from version 2.2, you can also use the `${artifact.properties.*}` property, as mentioned in the JIRA [MASSEMBLY-498](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY-498). This will reference custom properties you have set in this artifact inside the `<properties>` element.

So, for example, you could have:

```
<outputFileNameMapping>${artifact.artifactId}-${artifact.version}.noarch.rpm</outputFileNameMapping>
```

Note that the plugin *will* always rename the files based on that pattern. There is no option to skip the renaming.